# How to write a loop until (Python Anaconda)

Tags: python, loops, anaconda, pyautogui

I am using the Jupyter Notebook package and I would like to iterate the following commands a fixed number of times. Precisely, the script writes a range of width k=4347 and for each iteration this range should roll, until we get N= 798746.

One iteration is given by the following commands:

```
pyautogui.click(785, 263)
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click(885,11)
pyautogui.click(181, 347)
pyautogui.typewrite('**360795**', 0.25)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(292, 432)
pyautogui.typewrite('**365141**', 0.25)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(1348, 699)
time.sleep(180)
pyautogui.click(1335, 212)
```

I just want to iterate it in order not to do the "copy and paste" and then writing the ranges manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear for me what's the relation of `k` and `N` with your code snippet. Could you clarify?

Comment: N is some multiple of k, but not 'exact' multiple as in this case: I need to write all the ranges of width 4347 from 0 (or from 360795, as I don't need the previous this time) to 798746. So: 1-4347, 4348-8694 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing to me, but I think what you want it is something like:

Given a "work" you want to repeat multiple times:

```
def work():
    pyautogui.click(785, 263)
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.click(885,11)
    pyautogui.click(181, 347)
    pyautogui.typewrite('**360795**', 0.25)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(292, 432)
    pyautogui.typewrite('**365141**', 0.25)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(1348, 699)
    time.sleep(180)
    pyautogui.click(1335, 212)
```

You can loop over it while `k` is less than `N` by doing:

```
k = 0
N = 798746
while k < N:
    work()
    k += 4347
```

That is just a didactic example, there're more elegant ways of doing that.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I finally understood:

```
    N = 798746
    bold_number_value_1 = 360795
    bold_number_value_2 = 365141
    while bold_number_value_1 < N and bold_number_value_2 < N:
        pyautogui.click(785, 263)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.click(885,11)
        pyautogui.click(181, 347)
        pyautogui.typewrite('**{}**'.format(bold_number_value_1), 0.25)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(292, 432)
        pyautogui.typewrite('**{}**'.format(bold_number_value_2), 0.25)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(1348, 699)
        time.sleep(180)
        pyautogui.click(1335, 212)
        bold_number_value_1 += 4347
        bold_number_value_2 += 4347
```

Comment: I just want the numbers in bold increase by k in each iteration until 798746, sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I think I got it.. updated my answer. Even it still not what you want.. you can be based on that.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: If that is the correct answer you should mark it to help others with the same type of question.

Comment: I am still trying to make it working because I get some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop:

```
n = 0
max_n_value = 798746
while n < max_n_value:
    # Do your repeated code in here
    pyautogui.click(785, 263)
    time.sleep(5)
    n += 4347
```

This will loop until n is greater than your max N value.  Each iteration will add 4347, as you requested

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the feeling that this iterates N times. It seems to run the commands for each value of the range. I do not need it "for N in xrange". I need it writes here adding +4347 in each iteration until ite gets the end (798746):

    `pyautogui.typewrite('1', 0.25)`
    `time.sleep(1)`
   `pyautogui.click(292, 432)`
    `pyautogui.typewrite('4347', 0.25)`

Comment: @Macrina I've changed my answer after you clarified.  Use a while loop, and increment 'n' by 4347 each iteration, until you hit the maximum